# R CMD INSTALL: unknown option '--use-vanilla'

Tags: r

The help file of my R 4.1 says:

```
R CMD INSTALL --help
[...]
     --use-vanilla     do not read any Renviron or Rprofile files
[...]
```

Yet when I try to use it:

```
R CMD INSTALL --use-vanilla .
```

I get a warning:

> `Warning: unknown option '--use-vanilla'`

What is wrong in my setup?

---

Some more context. I am developing an app for a client, thus I am really interested in a solution for this particular R version. I am using RStudio build tools where, unfortunately, I cannot add a parameter to `R` like `R --vanilla INSTALL`.

For convenience I would love to find a workaround to get the same functionality to be able to stay in RStudio (will try the `R_INSTALL_VANILLA` approach), but if the ultimate answer is, this option will not work  in `R 4.1.` irrespective of what the help says and there is no quick bug fix other than upgrading, I guess i have to swallow this one then and call `INSTALL` from the command line then where I have more flexibility.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the `INSTALL` script.  If you read the [source code](http://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-4-3-branch/src/scripts/INSTALL), you'll see that the `--use-vanilla` argument is respected but wrongly passed to `R`, which knows about `--vanilla` but not `--use-vanilla`.

Comment: Actually, I think I've misunderstood the `while` loop and now I'm not so sure ...

Comment: The arg parsing in the source code looks fine to me. What do you get if you set R_INSTALL_VANILLA before running the command, e.g. R_INSTALL_VANILLA=true; R CMD INSTALL .`, instead of specifying 'vanilla' as an argument?

Comment: Somehow, that argument is seen by `tools:::.install_packages`, which prints the warning.  You can search the [source code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-4-3-branch/src/library/tools/R/install.R) for "unknown option".  Ideally, you would update R and let us know if the problem persists under the latest version.  I am able to pass `--use-vanilla` without warning ...

Comment: That you are calling `INSTALL` from RStudio's API and not from the command line is an important detail ... surely then it is a bug in RStudio, and you should file a report [there](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio), after checking first that the problem persists under the latest development version of RStudio ... Or do you also observe the warning when calling `INSTALL` from the command line? And are you unable to evaluate a suitable call to `utils::install.packages` or `tools::Rcmd`, instead of relying on the Build Tools?

Comment: Well, no, b/c I tried to run the same code from command line and it gave the same results. Looking into the source code which you kindly linked in your third comment, we see that `--use-vanilla` is only used in the help file but nowhere else.